# Не могу запустить команду в cron

Tags: bash, cron

есть команда синхронизации времени ntpdate 1.ro.pool.ntp.org
в крон пишу 00 11 * * * ntpdate 1.ro.pool.ntp.org но она не выполняется
а если пишу в терминале то все выполняется корректно
крон запускает из root

Comment: программа *ntpdate* предназначена для **однократной** установки текущего времени. она не предназначена для **поддержания** синхронизации времени. лучше использовать для этой цели те программы, которые специально для этого и написаны. например, *ntpd*.

Comment: `which ntpdate` что показывает

Comment: Убедитесь, что у вашего файла с заданиями, последняя строка оканчивается переводом строки.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что надо полностью писать, а вы пользователя не указали:

```
# m  h dom mon dow user  command
  0 11  *   *   *  root  ntpdate 1.ro.pool.ntp.org
```

Но это, как было указано выше, не совсем корректно так использовать синхронизацию времени.

Comment: это не является причиной, в новых версиях крон указание пользователя не обязательно, более вероятно что не указан PATH в задании крона, поэтому путь до ntpdate должен быть абсолютным.